# WallpaperManager wrong image size

Tags: android, wallpaper

I am working with WallpaperManager now. Here is my code:

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
wallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.some_image);
```

When I set [this image](http://www.mobilethemesworld.com/galaxy-s3-wallpaper/) as my wall paper, it is too large ([a screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17350105/wallpaper.png)), but I think the size (720*1280) is correct.

Even if I open the page by browser, and long click on the image, and then select the option to set wall paper, it's still the wrong size. Is there any thing I can do to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it finally.
The image size must be 1280*1280, not 720*1280.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to said that my device is S3.